# Prove: If $4k+1$ is a Quadratic Nonresidue mod $p$ then $k$ is a Quadratic Residue mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Prove the following:

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Suppose that $4k+1$ is a quadratic nonresidue $\mod p$. Then $k$ must be a quadratic residue.

My attempt at this was to suppose that $k$ is a quadratic nonresidue and show that $4k+1$ is a quadratic residue in order to get a contradiction, but I find it hard to compute $(4k+1)^\frac{p-1}{2}$ in order to use Euler's criterion.

Comment: We work modulo $p=7$. Then the squares are $1,2,4$. Consider $k=3$ now. Then $4k+1=13=6$ modulo $7$, and both $3,6$ are non-residues.

Comment: @Tanny Sieben: As you can see from dan_fulea's prior comment, the statement you are trying to prove is, in fact, false. Perhaps you copied the problem incorrectly? Can you tell us where is the problem from?

Comment: @dan_fulea . Also false when $k=3$ and $p=5$.